# How do I start yaws to run in embedded mode?

Tags: erlang, yaws

I've spent several hours trying to troubleshoot this issue using the yaws documentation and web searches. The existing threads here haven't helped me.

I am new to erlang and I am trying to run yaws in embedded mode using the sample code provided on http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws. I am missing something because I cannot get it to work. I have four files:

ybed.app

```
{application, ybed_app,
 [
  {description, "Yaws Embedded Application Test"},
  {vsn, "0.1.0"},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [kernel, stdlib, yaws]},
  {mod, {ybed_app, []}},
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

ybed_app.erl

```
-module(ybed_app).
-behaviour(application).

%% Application callbacks
-export([start/2,
         stop/1]).

start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    case ybed_sup:start_link() of
        {ok, Pid} ->
            {ok, Pid};
        Other ->
            {error, Other}
    end.

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

ybed_sup.erl

```
-module(ybed_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

%% API
-export([start_link/0]).

%% Supervisor callbacks
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    YBed = {ybed, {ybed,start,[]},
            permanent,2000,worker,[ybed]},
    {ok,{{one_for_all,0,1}, [YBed]}}.
```

ybed.erl

```
-module(ybed).
-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    {ok, spawn(?MODULE, run, [])}.

run() ->
    Id = "embedded",
    GconfList = [{id, Id}],
    Docroot = "/tmp",
    SconfList = [{port, 8000},
                 {servername, "foobar"},
                 {listen, {127,0,0,1}},
                 {docroot, Docroot}],
    {ok, SCList, GC, ChildSpecs} =
        yaws_api:embedded_start_conf(Docroot, SconfList, GconfList, Id),
    [supervisor:start_child(ybed_sup, Ch) || Ch <- ChildSpecs],
    yaws_api:setconf(GC, SCList),
     {ok, self()}.
```

When I compile it (successfully) and try to start the application, I get a return value:

```
{error,{not_loaded,yaws}}
```

When I try to run the compiled ybed.erl, ybed:run(), I get:

```
** exception error: undefined function yaws_api:embedded_start_conf/4
     in function  ybed:run/0 (src/ybed.erl, line 16)
```

If I start yaws before I start the application, it still doesn't work.

I am not trying to build releases yet, just compile and test yaws in embedded mode. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get error

```
** exception error: undefined function yaws_api:embedded_start_conf/4
     in function  ybed:run/0 (src/ybed.erl, line 16)
```

You clearly don't have `yaws_api.beam` in your [`code` server](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html) search path. Start your `erl` with proper `-pa` argument or call `code:add_patha/1` in your application initialization if you are not planning use embedded mode.

BTW there is a neat way how to start `yaws` under your own supervisor described in `yaws` documentation but without complete code so here we go in one module and with neat debugging resource and preparation for REST servicing.

```
-module(ybed_yaws).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-include_lib("yaws/include/yaws_api.hrl").

%% API
-export([start_link/0]).

%% Supervisor callbacks
-export([init/1]).

%% Internal functions export
-export([init_yaws/1, out/1]).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Defaults
%%%===================================================================

default_global() ->
    #{id => "yaws", logdir => "log"}.

default_server() ->
    #{port => 9900,
      listen => {0,0,0,0},
      docroot => "www",
      appmods => [{"/", ?MODULE}]}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% API functions
%%%===================================================================

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link(?MODULE, []).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Supervisor callbacks
%%%===================================================================

init([]) ->
    {ok,
     {{one_for_all, 0, 1},
      [#{id => init_yaws,
         start => {?MODULE, init_yaws, [self()]},
         restart => transient}]
     }}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================

init_yaws(Sup) ->
    {ok, proc_lib:spawn_link(fun() -> config(Sup) end)}.

ensure_dir(Dir) ->
    {ok, App} = application:get_application(),
    D = filename:join([code:priv_dir(App), Dir])
    filelib:ensure_dir(filename:join([D, "foo"])),
    D.

config(Supervisor) ->
    #{id := Id} = GCMap = default_global(),
    #{docroot := DR} = SCMap = default_server(),
    Docroot = ensure_dir(DR),
    {ok, SC, GC, ChildSpecs} =
        yaws_api:embedded_start_conf(
          Docroot,
          maps:to_list(SCMap#{docroot => Docroot}),
          maps:to_list(GCMap),
          Id),
    [supervisor:start_child(Supervisor, Ch) || Ch <- ChildSpecs],
    yaws_api:setconf(GC, SC),
    ok.

-compile({inline, [h/1, f/2]}).
h(A) when is_atom(A) -> h(atom_to_binary(A, latin1));
h(S) -> yaws_api:htmlize(S).

f(Fmt, Args) -> yaws_api:f(Fmt, Args).

box(Str) ->
    {'div',[{class,"box"}],
     {pre, [], h(Str)}}.

out(A) ->
    PathString = case A#arg.pathinfo of
               undefined -> "";
               P -> P
           end,
    Path = string:tokens(PathString, "/"),
    Method = A#arg.req#http_request.method,
    out(A, Method, Path).

out(A, Method, Path) ->
    {ehtml,
     {html, [],
      [{head},
       {body, [],
        [
         {h5, [], "Paths:"},
         {hr},
         box(f("Method = ~p~n"
               "Path = ~p~n"
               "A#arg.querydata = ~p~n",
               [Method,
                Path,
                A#arg.querydata])),
         {h5, [], "Headers:"},
         {hr},
         {ol, [], yaws_api:reformat_header(
                    A#arg.headers,
                    fun(H, V)->
                            {li, [], [h(H), ": ", {code, [], h(V)}]}
                    end
                   )}
        ]}
      ]}
    }.
```

Note the way how is `yaws` initialised in OTP compliant transient process but without `gen_server`.

Add `{yaws, [{embedded, true}]}` to your `.config` file to keep `yaws` application common services from starting. It will work even without it but it will not be fully embedded.

Comment: Thanks! It's the little things for noobs like me such as including all the beam paths into the VM or application configuration. This solved my problem.

Comment: This is beautiful and much appreciated. I was about to dig through some old code to find out how I did this a few years back and figured I might try Google.

Comment: One things that you can do if you want to cleanup the commend line and I did in my OTP application:start() to centralize things is using: `code:add_pathsa([?MODPATH_JSON, ?MODPATH_MYSQL, ?MODPATH_SMTP, ?MODPATH_INFLUX])`, Here I'm added the paths programatically... really just because I didn't want to have a long command line.